# How to align 2nd line of subcaption with first line?

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I am using subcaptions for describing multiple graphs that are located right next to each other. For longer subcaptions, I have the problem that the text is not nicely aligned with the second row slipping below the (a) and (b) labeling. Is there a way to align the beginning of the second row with the beginning of the subcaption text in row number 1?

Thanks so much for your help!

Attached is an example:

```
\documentclass[authoryear, review]{elsarticle} 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font = footnotesize, labelfont=bf]{subcaption}
\usepackage[font = footnotesize, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Sails}
        \caption{This is a rather long sub-caption for this nice picture of sails}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~ 
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.44\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Sails}
        \caption{This is a rather long sub-caption for this nice picture of sails}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{\textbf{This is the overall caption for this group of sailing pictures}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this setup:

```
\captionsetup[figure]{% use subfigure to confine changes to subcaptions
  justification = RaggedRight, % Or justified
  format=hang}
```

The complete example is like this:

```
\documentclass[authoryear, review]{elsarticle} 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font = footnotesize, labelfont=bf]{subcaption}
\usepackage[font = footnotesize, labelfont=bf]{caption}

\captionsetup[figure]{%
  justification = RaggedRight, % Or justified
  format=hang}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-A}
        \caption{This is a rather long sub-caption for this nice picture of sails}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~ 
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.44\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-B}
        \caption{This is a rather long sub-caption for this nice picture of sails}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{\textbf{This is the overall caption for this group of sailing pictures}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! This works well but it also edits the main captions. Can I somehow limit the proposed command to subcaptions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, stupid question! Works fine if I just use "subfigure" in your command instead of "figure". Thanks again for your help!

Comment: the baselines for the subcaptions are really too large; the lines should be closer together, with baselines suitable for the specified type size, i.e. (in this case) `\footnotesize`.  how to accomplish that?

Comment: @barbarabeeton  -- Adding `\usepackage{setspace}` in addition to `\captionsetup[subfigure]{font=footnotesize, format=hang}` should automatically accomplish this. In fact, `setspace` can set the correct font by itself also.

Comment: @barbara  I think this is mainly due to the "review" option in the elsarticle class, which increases line spaces for convenient review. If you use "preprint" instead, I think the linespace looks fine to me. Or would you still say it is too large?

Comment: @AboAmmar, would the setspace package still be of benefit to me even in the elsarticle - "preprint" option given that there is no double-spacing anymore?